# Does there exist a subset of N satisfying a certain density property

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, natural-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

If $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ we say that the set $A$ has a natural density if the limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|A\cap [1,n]|}{n}$$
exists and we denote it by $d(A)$. Also for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$
and $\ell\in {0,1,\dots,k-1}$ we define the set $A_{k\mathbb{N}+\ell}$ to be
$$A_{k\mathbb{N}+\ell}=\{\alpha\in A: \textrm{there} \ 
\textrm{exist} \ m\in\mathbb{N} \ \textrm{with} \ \alpha=km+\ell\}.$$
**My question is the following:**

> Does there exist a subset $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ with natural density
> $0<d(A)<1$ and the  property that  for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and
> $\ell\in {0,1,\dots,k-1}$ one has
> $$d(A_{k\mathbb{N}+\ell})=\frac{d(A)}{k}?$$

**Edit:** Let me give you some motivation about the aforementioned question.

This question arose when I tried to prove another property of the
natural density. More specifically, given a set $A\subset \mathbb{N}$
with natural density $d(A)>0$ and a number $0<b<d(A)$ I wanted to
prove that there exists a $B\subset A$ with natural density $d(B)=b$.

Although this seems very natural, the proof isn't easy at all.
My proof was based on a constructive argument. I approached the requested density
by eliminating terms that belonged in appropriate arithmetic progressions.
In this way, as I noticed, I was changing the "proportion" of terms in
these specific arithmetic progressions. So, I thought that maybe there is
a way to do that without influence the "proportion".
Starting from $\mathbb{N}$ I tried to construct sets with positive
densities with the property that their terms have in some sense
"uniform distribution" on arithmetic progressions.
So finally I
formulated this problem in my mind.

When $d(A)=0$ or $d(A)=1$ the
answer is yes and it is trivial.
The problem I encountered was that when you try to "distribute"
terms, for examble, on $2\mathbb{N}$ and $2\mathbb{N}+1$ you
have already affect the "proportion" of terms on $4\mathbb{N}+\ell$.
So, I thought that the key was to do it for the progressions of the
form $p\mathbb{N}+\ell$ where p is prime. But I am stack here.
My intuition says that there must be a way. Maybe my previous attempt
on the initial problem have me "binded" and I can't think in a different
more sophisticated
way.

In case if anyone is interested, I would really like to have some thoughts on this problem.

Thanks
in regards.

Comment: $1,4,6,7,10,11,13,16,18,19,21,24,25,28,30,31,\dots$. https://oeis.org/A026147

Comment: Or maybe https://oeis.org/A054683 numbers with even digit sum: $2,4,6,8,11,13,15,17,19,20,22,24,26,28,31,\dots,97,99,101,103,105,107,109,110,\dots$.

Comment: Or maybe https://oeis.org/A022844 the integer part of $n\pi$, $n=1,2,3,\dots$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you very much for your responce! Indeed all these exambles work. Especially the second one is very self explanatory! Now i am wondering if one can construct a non syndetic set with this property, maybe using these exambles. If you have an idea it would be very enlighting to me.

Comment: You'll have to remind me of the meaning of *nonsyndetic*. Also, it might be worth looking at the Kuipers & Niederreiter book on Uniform Distribution Modulo One.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you very much for the book! It contains many theorems and exambles in this direction. A syndetic set is a subset of the natural numbers that the sizes of the gaps between its terms is bounded.  I believe I found a way to construct suck a set using a theorem from the book! Thank you very much again!

Comment: Let me encourage you to write up what you have found, and to post it as an answer.

Comment: You could do that today.